# how to use Conditional operator when setting a value to sql parameter

Tags: c#

I have a stored procedure accepting @from_date = NULL.
I have a variable dayCount. If its value is 0, I have to pass Null as param. Else DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayCount).

My code goes like this.

```
int dayCount = -7;
SqlParameter[] parameters =
{    
new SqlParameter("@from_date", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = (dayCount==0)? null : (DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayCount)) }                        
};
```

i'm getting error in `(dayCount==0)? null : (DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayCount))`.

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int dayCount = -7;
SqlParameter[] parameters =
{
       new SqlParameter("@from_date", SqlDbType.VarChar) 
       { 
            Value = dayCount == 0 ? null : (DateTime?)(DateTime.Today.AddDays(dayCount))
       }
};
```

`DateTime` cannot be null (as it is a struct) so you have to cast it to `Nullable DataTime` to use it in conditional operator.